# sudo ssh asks for passphrase when it shouldn't

Tags: ssh, sudo

I am able to `ssh user@remotemachine` without password using a keypair with an empty passphrase. However, when I do `sudo -u user ssh user@remotemachine` it keeps asking for a passphrase. Also `sudo -u user ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa user@remotemachine` doesn't help. Why is that?

Background: I am running a python script as sudo, and from this script I need to ssh to remotemachine as user.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT

In reply to comment, I retried with the -vv option. Everything looks fine, the key is found, sent to server, and accepted. However, then come the following lines:

```
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp <here was the fingerprint>
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Comment: Add the `-vv` option to your ssh command.  I guess you it is refusing to use your key or not finding it for some reason.  Which should be mentioned in the verbose output.

Answer (score 0):

All right, it was my own fault. The key was actually encrypted, as I could see by opening it in a text editor. The fact that without sudo I was not asked for a passphrase was because I already entered the passphrase upon login (I guess it's some gnome utility that caches it) and forgot about it because of the long uptime :)

With sudo, I guess, I could not access this cached password.

To decrypt a private key, you can use `openssl rsa -in id_rsa -out id_rsa.decr`, then `rm id_rsa`, followed by `mv id_rsa.decr id_rsa`.